# TSLint : variable name must be in camelcase or uppercase

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have some variable names starting with leading underscore , I still get this warning after updating my tslint.json

**tslint.json**

```
{
  "extends": "tslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "variable-name": [
      true,
      "ban-keywords",
      "check-format",
      "allow-leading-underscore"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "build/**/*",
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "tmp/**/*"
  ]
}
```

where am I wrong ?

thanks for feedback

UPDATE

I am using version 4.5.1 of TSLint

Comment: Looks right to me at a glance, what version of TSLint are you using?

Comment: I am using currently version 4.5.1.

Comment: Can you verify that TSLint is indeed using that config file? See if other changes to it affect things?

Comment: You right ... 
using tslint --project '.' --config ./tslint.json
it works now ...  I don't understand why tslint was not using it when not specified... ( maybe weird behaviour w Webstorm IDE.. I'm using it..)

Answer (score 85):

You can solve the problem by editing your `tslint.json` and adding `"allow-leading-underscore"` to the `"variable-name"` array of your `"rules"`.

```
// tslint.json contents
{
  // ...
  "rules": {
    // ...
    "variable-name": [
      true,
      // ...
      "allow-leading-underscore"
    ]
  },
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 23):

I have updated `tslint.json`, configured the file and added optional arguments to the array of variable-name.

> `"allow-leading-underscore"` allows underscores at the beginning (only has an effect if “check-format” specified)
>
> `"allow-pascal-case"` allows PascalCase in addition to lowerCamelCase.
>
> `"allow-snake-case"` allows snake_case in addition to lowerCamelCase.
>
> `"allow-trailing-underscore"` allows underscores at the end. (only has an effect if “check-format” specified)

```
{
  // ...
  "rules": {
    "variable-name": [
      true,
      "allow-leading-underscore"
    ],
  },
  // ...
}
```

You can configure `tslint.json` according to your requirements.

This link might be helpful. https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/variable-name/

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem by editing your tslint.json and adding all this properties to the "variable-name" :

```
"variable-name": {
  "options": [
    "ban-keywords",
    "check-format",
    "allow-pascal-case",
    "allow-leading-underscore",
    "allow-snake-case",
    "allow-trailing-underscore",
    "require-const-for-all-caps"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the more complete example.