# How can i configure tslint to not throw warning when underscore in a variable name?

Tags: typescript, tslint

How can i configure tslint to not throw warning when underscore in a variable name in typescript?

For Example:

interface MyInterface{
USER_ID :number
}

This throw "variable name must be in lowerCamelCase or UPPER_CASE" error....I cant change the variable name....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TSLint : variable name must be in camelcase or uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099747/tslint-variable-name-must-be-in-camelcase-or-uppercase)

Answer (score 0):

You can either the rule [variable-name](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/variable-name/) on your tslint.json, or better configure it to suit your specific needs (See the check-format argument for further info)